# New monitor and eyes problem

Tags: mac, macbook, display

I recently bought a LG FLatron W2442PE monitor to use it as external and main monitor for my macbookpro 15 (2008) using a dvi conector. I use a 1920 x 1080 resolution, 60Hz, and all the monitor settings are default. Since I bought it I am start to have some vision problems; double vision and blurring. I wonder if this has ever happened to you and which setttings/setups would you recommend me

Comment: A low-strength pair of glasses.

Comment: Do you have this problem with one or both eyes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setup I'd recommend to you is called **Ophthalmologist**.

Seriously though: This should not happen. Don't take any community advise on something that could cause health problems. In that case you might just need a good pair of glasses.